# Proving the existence of a Gelfand transform

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, gelfand-representation

If $A$ is a commutative Banach algebra and $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, where $\Omega$ contains $\mathscr{R}(\hat{x})$, I want to prove the existence of a $y\in A$ with $\hat{y}=f\circ\hat{x}$, where $x\in A$.

We have that $\mathscr{R}(\hat{x})=\sigma(x)$ for all $x\in A$. Thus, since $f$ is holomorphic in the open set which contains $\sigma(x)$, it follows that $\Omega\equiv A_{\Omega}$ and $f\equiv\tilde{f}\in \tilde{H}(A_{\Omega})$. Hence
    $$
 \tilde{f}\circ\hat{x}=\tilde{f}(h(x))=\tilde{f}(\sigma(x)),
 $$
    where $h\in\Delta$ is a complex homomorphism.

Since $f:A_{\Omega}\to\mathbb{C}$ and $h:A\to\mathbb{C}$, it follows that $f\circ\hat{x}$ is a complex homomorphism of $A_{\Omega}$. So we can compute that $\|f\circ\hat{x}\|_{\infty}=\max_{h\in\Delta}|f(h(x))|\le\|x\|$ for all $x\in A_{\Omega}$. Then by the Hahn-Banach theorem it follows that $f\circ\hat{x}$ extends to a complex linear functional $\phi$ on $A$ that satisfies $|\phi(x)|\le\|x\|$ for all $x\in A$.

I still have to show that the range of $\phi(x)$ is $\sigma(f(x))$, and that $\phi$ is a homomorphism, then $\phi\equiv y$, essentially. But I don't know how to proceed. There is a theorem in Rudin's *Functional Analysis* (10.29), which I think could be of use and it states that $\tilde{h}=\tilde{g}\circ\tilde{f}$ if $h=g\circ f$. Essentially that was what I was working towards.

Comment: If $A_\Omega= \{x \in A, \sigma(x) \subset \Omega\}$ then $f$ holomorphic on $\Omega$ means [that f can be extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus#Functional_calculus_for_a_bounded_operator) as a holomorphic function $A_\Omega \to A$ (not $A_\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of how to complete exercise via the path you're following, however there is a fairly simple solution. This will follow the notation of Rudin's *Functional Analysis*.  Using the functional calculus, put
$$y=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma f(\lambda)(\lambda e-x)^{-1}\ d\lambda, $$
where $\Gamma$ surrounds $\sigma(x)$ in $\Omega$.  For $h\in\Delta$, we have
$$h(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma f(\lambda)h((\lambda e-x)^{-1})\ d\lambda
=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma\frac{f(\lambda)}{\lambda-h(x) }\ d\lambda =f(h(x)),$$
and therefore $\hat{y}=f\circ\hat{x}$.

Comment: @user1952009 Rudin uses a lot of notation that can be confusing on a first read through.

Comment: What about $h(x) \in \Omega$ ? Does it follow from $h \in \Delta, \sigma(x) \subset \Omega$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Yes.  Observe that $h(x-h(x)e)=h(x)-h(x)=0$, so $x-h(x)e$ is not invertible, and thus $h(x)\in\sigma(x)\subset\Omega$.

Comment: how are you claiming that your $y\in A$

Comment: @bunny Because $A$ is a Banach algebra, hence closed under holomorphic functional calculus.

Comment: can you provide me any reference to read about your statement

Comment: Chapter 10 of Rudin's *Functional Analysis* is where I learned about the holomorphic functional calculus.  Another good source is somewhere in Conway's functional analysis book.